# Problems with certificate with wget and github lately

Tags: git, ssl

Lately, I have received errors while using wget against github on ubuntu 10.04.

```
ERROR: certificate common name `*.github.com' doesn't match requested host name `github.com'.
To connect to github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Does anyone know why this error ocours and how to fix it (without --no-check-certificate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, github.com is no longer using a wildcard certificate, and they use a certificate specifically for `github.com`.
You need to obtain the new SSL certificate for github.com and put that in your system's certificate store, in `/etc/ssl/certs`.

You can get the new certificate using the command

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect github.com:443
```

In any case, the certificate is

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Once you put it in `/etc/ssl/certs`, `wget` will recognise it.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Would I also need to add a symbolic link to that certificate file?